# making a word search puzzle?

Tags: c, arrays, char

I've made a program that allows you to choose the size of the grid and it allows you to enter up to 20 words.  Now I have to insert the entered words horizontally into the original array using a function.  The function must return a value for success and a value for failure to enter the word into the puzzle board.  I need help getting started with what the actual function should look like along with the function prototype.  Pseudocode would be helpful.  I'm a fairly new programmer so any help is great.  Thank you

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void printmatrix(char matrix[][20],int);
void inserthor(char matrix[][20],int);

int main(void)
{
    //declare variables
    char matrix[20][20];
    char words[20][100];

    int x;
    int a,b;
    int i=0;
    int n=0;

    for (a=0;a<20;a++)
    {
        for (b=0;b<20;b++)
        {
            matrix[a][b] = '+';
        }
    }

    while (x<10 || x>20)
    {
        printf("How large would you like the puzzle to be (between 10 and 20):\n");
        scanf("%d",&x);
    }

    printmatrix(matrix,x);

    //part 3

    printf("Enter up to 20 words to hide in the puzzle.\n");
    printf("Enter the word 'done' after your last word if entering less than 20 words.\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter word %2d:\n", i+1);
        if (scanf("%99s", words[i]) != 1 || strcmp(words[i], "done") == 0)
            break;
    }
    n = i;
    printf("%d words entered\n", n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("Word %2d = [%s]\n", i+1, words[i]);
    return 0;
}

void printmatrix(char matrix[][20],int x)
{
    int i,j;
    printf("Empty Puzzle:\n");

    for (i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<x;j++)
        {
            printf(" %c ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function prototype

```
void inserthor(char matrix[][20],int);
```

lacks the parameter with the word to be entered and the value to be returned. You could use

```
char *inserthor(char matrix[][20], int order, char *word)
{
    int i, j, l = strlen(word);
    for (i = 0; i < order; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j <= order-l; ++j)
        if (matrix[i][j] == '+') return memcpy(&matrix[i][j], word, l);
    return NULL;
}
```

which returns the address of the inserted word for success and `NULL` for failure.